# Angular 6 trust only iframes in innerHtml

Tags: angular, iframe, angular-dom-sanitizer

I have an Api that responds with Html. I don't want to fully trust the content because of xss.

But sometimes I'll have Iframes in the response that I want to trust based on a whitelist.

I'm aware of the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` possibility but I didn't find out how to partially trust Html.

For example:
Api response

```
<p>Some test text<br class='autobr' />\n<strong>some 
more</strong></p>\n<iframe 
src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/289729765\" width=\"640\" 
height=\"360\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen 
mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>\n<p><a 
href=\"https://vimeo.com/289729765\">Mike Hopkins: The 
Backyard</a> from <a 
href=\"https://vimeo.com/diamondback\">Diamondback Bicycles</a> 
on <a href=\"https://vimeo.com\">Vimeo</a>.</p>\n<p>and the 
end</p>
```

Then I want to trust the Iframe only and display the whole text like this: `<div innerHtml="myResponse"></div>`

I tried extracting the iframe, trusting it and then replace it with the trusted `SafeHtml`. That didn't work. 
Is there any possibility to partially bypassSecurityTrustHtml()?

I am working with Angular 6...

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong Attribute Binding Syntax.

```
<div innerHtml="myResponse"></div>
```

Should have been

```
<div [innerHTML]="myResponse"></div>
```

PS - Not sure if that's just a typo or an actual syntax issue at your end.

Comment: sorry that's a typo